# The funcion onclick only takes one operation

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, calculator

I am trying to make a simple calculator with multiple buttons, but somehow it only takes the operation '+' and the #dot doesnt work. any help or tips?

```
        var input='', acc=0, operation='';
        
        function btn(x){ 
            switch(x){  
                case '=':{
                    if (operation=='+'){
                        input=acc+Number(input);
                    }else
                    if (operation=='*'){
                        input=acc*Number(input);
                    };
                    document.querySelector('#dot').disabled=false;
                    break;
                }  

                case '*':{
                    acc=Number(input);
                        operation='*';
                };      
                case '+':{
                    acc=Number(input);
                        operation='+';
                }; 
                case 'c': 
                    input='';
                    document.querySelector('#dot').disabled=false;
                break;
                case '_':
                    document.querySelector('#dot').disabled=true; 
                default:
                    input+=String(x);
            };
            document.querySelector('.display').innerText=input;
            
        }
```

Comment: what is the value of `x` inside function `btn(x)`?

Comment: It can be between 1-9 or '+' '-'. Does that answer the question?